# Programatically Select a combobox item using the SelectedValue WPF

Tags: wpf

I have a combo box which is loaded through a Datasource(Datatable). On a scenario I want the combo box to load with the desired value which I would be passing as combobox1.SelectedValue = custId (Say it's a customer details). custID is set as SelectedValuePath in XAML. When I set that, I am getting a null exception. Anything I am missing?

My XAML:

```
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="332,42,0,0" Name="cmbCustomerName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="240" IsEditable="True" DisplayMemberPath="customername" SelectedValuePath="custid" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource cust}" SelectionChanged="cmbCustomerName_SelectionChanged" AllowDrop="True" FontWeight="Normal" Text="--Select a Customer Name--" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />
```

**UPDATE:**

C# code:

```
public customer(int custid)
{
   InitializeComponent();
   cmbcustomer.SelectedValue= custid.ToString();
}

private void cmbCustomerName_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      cmbcustid.SelectedValue= cmbcustomer.SelectedValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue resolved by assigning the value in the combox_loaded event, as the combobox was just initialized in the constructor, but it was not loaded from the datasource.

Answer (score 0):

The selectedValue would not work in this scenario,you should use selectedItem instead,for example:

combobox1.SelectedItem = "custId";

or

combobox1.Text = "custId";

or

combobox1.SelectedIndex = combobox1.Items.IndexOf("custId");

or

combobox1.SelectedIndex = combobox1.FindStringExact("custId")

Comment: No.. I tried that as well. It doesn't throws any exception, but it is assigning null value. I have a selection changed event attached with combo box which doesnt triggers

Comment: the value would be dynamic. I don know what string would be passed. Your updated answers will not work

Comment: Update your question with C# code snippet to help you better.

Comment: Assigning through a constructor calling from different wpf window.

Comment: Are you using method invoker to update your UIelement?

Comment: MainWindow.myInstance.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate() {MainWindow.myInstance.myTextBox.Text = "some text";});

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you a method

> This is hackish. This is bad coding format.

```
// Remove the handler
cmbcustomer.SelectionChanged -= cmbCustomerName_SelectionChanged;
// Make a selection...
cmbcustomer.SelectedIndex = combobox1.Items.IndexOf(custid.ToString()); //<-- do not want to raise
// SelectionChanged event programmatically here
// Add the handler again.
cmbcustomer.SelectionChanged += cmbCustomerName_SelectionChanged;
```

As a temporary solution you can try this out

Comment: it didnt work.. the selecteditem is still null :( Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Wait to access any properties of the `ComboBox`es until the they have been loaded:

```
private void cmbCustomerName_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(cmbcustid != null && cmbcustid.IsLoaded && cmbcustomer != null && cmbcustomer.IsLoaded)
        cmbcustid.SelectedValue = cmbcustomer.SelectedValue;
}
```